# Apps Script: How to limit the scope of a FOR LOOP?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script

The script below runs whenever any cell in **column E** (so, **array [4]**) has been edited. And its only purpose is to add some additional information to the **subsequent empty cells** of the row that has been edited. But instead of just adding these information to the next cells that are empty in the same row, my script is re-setting the values of all subsequent cells, even if these subsequent cells already have each some values in them. Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong here and how to fix it? It´s obvious that I am doing something wrong in my **IF-statement**, but I honestly have no idea what that could be :(

Thank you so much in advance for your help and hints!!!

---

**Here is the script:**

```
function addAdditionalInfo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('SHEET_ID');
  var data = s.getDataRange().getValues();
  var data_len = data.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < data_len; i++) {
    if (data[i][4] == "COMPLETED") {
      s.getRange(i + 1, 6).setValue("name");
      s.getRange(i + 1, 7).setValue("street");
      s.getRange(i + 1, 8).setValue("street number");
      s.getRange(i + 1, 9).setValue("zip code");
      s.getRange(i + 1, 10).setValue("country");
      s.getRange(i + 1, 11).setValue("maternal language");
      s.getRange(i + 1, 12).setValue("second language");
      s.getRange(i + 1, 13).setValue("-");
    }
    else if (data[i][4] == "APPROVAL") {
      s.getRange(i + 1, 6).setValue("name of supervisor)");
      s.getRange(i + 1, 7).setValue("email of supervisor");
      s.getRange(i + 1, 8).setValue("tel of supervisor");
      s.getRange(i + 1, 9).setValue("maternal language of supervisor");
      s.getRange(i + 1, 10).setValue("second language of supervisor");
      s.getRange(i + 1, 11).setValue("assistant of the supervisor");
      s.getRange(i + 1, 12).setValue("status of the approval process");
      s.getRange(i + 1, 13).setValue("approval due date");
    }
  }
}
```

**And here is the trigger:**

```
// The trigger is any manual change done in Column E, starting at row 3 of that column
function onEdit(e) {
  if (
    e.source.getSheetName() == "SHEET_ID" &&
    e.range.columnStart == 5 &&
    e.range.columnEnd == 5 &&
    e.range.rowStart >= 3 &&
    e.range.rowEnd <= 3000
  ) {
    addAdditionalInfo()
  }
}
```

Comment: @Tanaike  - If you are around, would you be so nice to give me some hint and/point me in the right direction? And do you have any suggestions for me, @Cooper? That would be really nice. Thanks :)

Comment: What  do you think does `e.range.rowStart` contains? And what is the range referred by `e.range`?

Comment: @TheMaster - `e.range.rowStart` is in column E and contains the same dropdown that all other cells in that column E have. And `e.range.rowStart` is also the first non-empty row in that very same column E. Any change occuring in the sheet starts, as soon as an option has been chosen by the user in that column E. Have I fully answered your question? Thanks :)

Comment: @TheMaster - `e.range` refers to the cell that has been edited. You seem to imply I shouldn´t use it at all? Or what I am missing here? Thanks :)

Comment: Can you provide a sample sheet we can work on @BobHardball?

Comment: @ASyntuBU - Thanks for getting in touch. I´d rather solve the problem without having to share the sheet. So, which additional information can I make available to you, so that we can move on? Thanks :)

Comment: The onEdit(e) function is not the trigger.  It is the trigger handler.  The trigger is generated when someone edits a cell in the spreadsheet.

Comment: I'm implying you don't need a loop at all. Why loop  through every row, when you already have the row and the range you need to check- in your hands already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Adding data to just line that you are on will limit the scope

Trying to loop through the entire sheet is a bad idea since this script will max out after 30 seconds.

In my testing I used a validation in column 5  using the list `COMPLETED,APPROVAL`

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('entry')
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart == 5 && e.range.rowStart > 2) {
    e.source.toast('completed');
    if (e.value == "COMPLETED") {
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 6, 1, 8).setValues([["name", "street", "street number", "zip code", "country", "maternal language", "second language", "-"]]);
    }
    if (e.value == "APPROVAL") {
      e.source.toast('approval')
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 6, 1, 8).setValues([["name of supervisor", "email of supervisor", "tel of supervisor", "maternal language of supervisor", "second language of supervisor", "assistant of the supervisor", "status of the approval process", "approval due date"]]);
    }
  }
}
```

Sheet0:

[image]

Comment: I said it before and NEED to say it again: You are a Legen - with a big "L"!!! Not only DID your script did the trick, but it also opened my eyes to way more possibilities in my attempt to improve my Apps script coding skills. Thank you! Thank you! and THANK YOU!!!! Especially about the need for using loops a little bit more carefully.